# How to get the access token of the service account running a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I have a google cloud function that is sending a PATCH request to the GCP app engine admin API to modify a service. I have a assigned a service account to the cloud function that has the required IAM permissions to modify app engine services, but i get a 401 unauthorized error when i test the function. It seems that google cant automatically detect that the request being send to the app engine admin API is authorized by that service account, so how do i get the access token of the service account running the cloud function so i can include it into the api call?

This is my current function:

```
functions.http('toggleFingerprintServer', async (req, res) => {
    
    //get access token of service account running this function here and attack to request below to gain access to API

    if (!req.query || !req.query.servingStatus || (req.query.servingStatus!== 'SERVING' &&  req.query.servingStatus!== 'STOPPED'))
        res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: "Status must be SERVING or STOPPED"})
    else {
        const externalRes = await fetch('https://content-appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/demoApp/services/fingerprint-api/versions/1?updateMask=servingStatus', {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({servingStatus: req.query.servingStatus}),
        });
        res.sendStatus(externalRes.ok ? 200 : 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you need an access token. You could get it manually (using the [metadata server and calling the correct URL](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview)), but you can also leverage the built-in solution of Google Cloud client library like that

```
    const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
...
...

    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });
    const token = await auth.getAccessToken();
    console.log(token);
```

Comment: this is the correct solution, to anyone else trying to do this, do not try and manually authethicate to the oauth2 server, it is extremely painfull.